Why doesn't my iterator work with std::copy algorithm?
Why does my Iterator class inside MojVektor (which is something like std::vector) not work with the std::copy() algorithm?
MojVektor.hpp
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

template <typename T>
class MojVektor {
private:
    size_t capacity_;
    size_t size_;
    T* arr_;

    void realoc() {
        capacity_ *= 2;
        T* tempArr = arr_;
        arr_ = new T[capacity_];
        std::copy(tempArr, tempArr + size_, arr_);
        delete[] tempArr;
        return;
    }

public:
    class Iterator;

    MojVektor() : capacity_{ 10 }, size_{ 0 }, arr_{ new T[capacity_] } {};

    MojVektor(const std::initializer_list<T>& list) : capacity_{ list.size() }, size_{ list.size() }, arr_{ new T[capacity_] } {
        std::copy(list.begin(), list.end(), arr_);
        return;
    }

    MojVektor(const MojVektor& second) : capacity_{ second.capacity_ }, size_{ second.size_ }, arr_{ new T[capacity_] } {
        std::copy(second.arr_, second.arr_ + size_, arr_);
        return;
    }

    MojVektor& operator=(const MojVektor& second) {
        capacity_ = second.capacity_;
        size_ = second.size_;
        arr_ = new T[capacity_];
        std::copy(second.arr_, second.arr_ + size_, arr_);
        return *this;
    }

    MojVektor(MojVektor&& second) : capacity_{ std::move(second.capacity_) }, size_{ std::move(second.size_) }, arr_{ std::move(second.arr_) } {
        second.capacity_ = 0;
        second.size_ = 0;
        second.arr_ = nullptr;
        return;
    }

    MojVektor& operator=(MojVektor&& second) {
        capacity_ = std::move(second.capacity_);
        size_ = std::move(second.size_);
        arr_ = std::move(second.arr_);
        second.capacity_ = 0;
        second.size_ = 0;
        second.arr_ = nullptr;
        return *this;
    }

    ~MojVektor() {
        delete[] arr_;
        size_ = 0;
        capacity_ = 0;
        return;
    }

    MojVektor& push_back(const T& e) {
        if (arr_ == nullptr) {
            capacity_ = 10;
            arr_ = new T[capacity_];
        }
        if (size_ >= capacity_) {
            realoc();
        }
        arr_[size_] = e;
        ++size_;
        return *this;
    }

    MojVektor& push_front(const T& e) {
        if (arr_ == nullptr) {
            capacity_ = 10;
            arr_ = new T[capacity_];
        }
        if (size_ >= capacity_) {
            realoc();
        }
        for (T* endIndex = arr_ + size_ - 1; endIndex >= arr_; --endIndex) {
            *(endIndex + 1) = std::move(*(endIndex));
        }
        *(arr_) = e;
        ++size_;
        return *this;
    }

    MojVektor& push_back(T&& e) {
        if (arr_ == nullptr) {
            capacity_ = 10;
            arr_ = new T[capacity_];
        }
        if (size_ >= capacity_) {
            realoc();
        }
        arr_[size_] = std::move(e);
        ++size_;
        return *this;
    }

    MojVektor& push_front(T&& e) {
        if (arr_ == nullptr) {
            capacity_ = 10;
            arr_ = new T[capacity_];
        }
        if (size_ >= capacity_) {
            realoc();
        }
        for (T* endIndex = arr_ + size_ - 1; endIndex >= arr_; --endIndex) {
            *(endIndex + 1) = std::move(*(endIndex));
        }
        *(arr_) = std::move(e);
        ++size_;
        return *this;
    }

    size_t size() const {
        return size_;
    }

    T& at(size_t index) const {
        if (index < 0 || index > size_ - 1) {
            throw std::out_of_range("Index out of range!");
        }
        return *(arr_ + index);
    }

    T& operator[](size_t index) const {
        return *(arr_ + index);
    }

    void clear() {
        capacity_ = 0;
        size_ = 0;
        delete[] arr_;
        arr_ = nullptr;
        return;
    }

    void resize(size_t newSize, const T& difference_value) {
        if (newSize < size_) {
            size_ = newSize;
        }
        else if (newSize > size_) {
            T* tempArr = arr_;
            capacity_ = newSize;
            arr_ = new T[capacity_];
            std::copy(tempArr, tempArr + size_, arr_);
            while (size_ < newSize) {
                arr_[size_] = difference_value;
                ++size_;
            }
        }
        return;
    }

    MojVektor& pop_back() {
        if (size_ == 0) {
            throw std::out_of_range("Vector is empty!");
        }
        --size_;
        return *this;
    }

    MojVektor& pop_front() {
        if (size_ == 0) {
            throw std::out_of_range("Vector is empty!");
        }
        for (T* beginIndex = arr_; beginIndex < arr_ + size_; ++beginIndex) {
            *(beginIndex) = std::move(*(beginIndex + 1));
        }
        --size_;
        return *this;
    }

    T& back() const {
        if (size_ == 0) {
            throw std::out_of_range("Vector is empty!");
        }
        return arr_[size_ - 1];
    }

    T& front() const {
        if (size_ == 0) {
            throw std::out_of_range("Vector is empty!");
        }
        return *arr_;
    }

    bool empty() const {
        return size_ == 0;
    }

    size_t capacity() const {
        return capacity_;
    }

    bool operator==(const MojVektor& second) const {
        if (size_ != second.size_) {
            return false;
        }
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size_; ++i) {
            if ((this->operator[](i)) != second[i]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    bool operator!=(const MojVektor& second) const {
        return !(this->operator==(second));
    }

    bool full() const {
        return size_ == capacity_;
    }

    MojVektor subvector(Iterator beginIt, Iterator endIt) const {
        if (beginIt < begin() || endIt > end()) {
            throw std::out_of_range("Iterators out of range!");
        }
        MojVektor v;
        while (beginIt != endIt) {
            v.push_back(*beginIt);
            ++beginIt;
        }
        return v;
    }

    Iterator begin() const {
        return Iterator(arr_);
    }

    Iterator end() const {
        return Iterator(arr_ + size_);
    }

    Iterator find(const T& value) const {
        Iterator it = begin();
        while (it != end()) {
            if (*(it) == value) {
                return it;
            }
            ++it;
        }
        return it;
    }

    Iterator erase(Iterator pos) {
        if (pos < begin() || pos > end()) {
            throw std::out_of_range("Iterator out of range!");
        }
        if (pos == end()) {
            return end();
        }
        Iterator it{ pos };
        while (it != end()) {
            *(it) = std::move(*(it + 1));
            ++it;
        }
        --size_;
        return pos;
    }

    Iterator insert(Iterator pos, const T& e) {
        size_t index = pos - begin();
        if (index < 0 || index >= size_) {
            throw std::out_of_range("Iterator out of range!");
        }
        if (size_ >= capacity_) {
            realoc();
        }
        if (index == 0) {
            push_front(e);
        }
        else {
            for (size_t i = size_; i >= index; --i) {
                *(arr_ + i + 1) = std::move(*(arr_ + i));
            }
            arr_[index] = e;
            ++size_;
        }
        return Iterator{ arr_ + index };
    }

    Iterator insert(Iterator pos, T&& e) {
        size_t index = pos - begin();
        if (index < 0 || index >= size_) {
            throw std::out_of_range("Iterator out of range!");
        }
        if (size_ >= capacity_) {
            realoc();
        }
        if (index == 0) {
            push_front(std::move(e));
        }
        else {
            for (size_t i = size_; i >= index; --i) {
                *(arr_ + i + 1) = std::move(*(arr_ + i));
            }
            arr_[index] = std::move(e);
            ++size_;
        }
        return Iterator{ arr_ + index };
    }

    Iterator rbegin() const {
        return end() - 1;
    }

    Iterator rend() const {
        return begin() - 1;
    }

    Iterator erase(Iterator beginIt, Iterator endIt) {
        size_t beginIndex = beginIt - begin();
        size_t endIndex = endIt - begin();
        if (beginIndex > endIndex || beginIndex < 0 || endIndex > size_ || beginIndex > size_) {
            throw std::out_of_range("Iterators out of range!");
        }
        for (size_t i = beginIndex; i < endIndex; ++i) {
            arr_[i] = std::move(arr_[endIndex - beginIndex + i]);
        }
        size_ -= (endIndex - beginIndex);
        return Iterator{ arr_ + beginIndex };
    }

    void rotate() {
        for (size_t beginIndex = 0, endIndex = size_ - 1; beginIndex < endIndex; ++beginIndex, --endIndex) {
            std::swap(arr_[beginIndex], arr_[endIndex]);
        }
        return;
    }

    void rotate(Iterator beginIt, Iterator endIt) {
        size_t beginIndex = beginIt - Iterator(arr_);
        size_t endIndex = (endIt - Iterator(arr_)) - 1;
        if (beginIndex > endIndex || beginIndex < 0 || endIndex > size_ || beginIndex > size_) {
            throw std::out_of_range("Iterators out of range!");
        }
        while (beginIndex < endIndex) {
            std::swap(arr_[beginIndex], arr_[endIndex]);
            ++beginIndex;
            --endIndex;
        }
        return;
    }

    T* data() {
        return arr_;
    }
};

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& outputStream, const MojVektor<T>& container) {
    const size_t size = container.size();
    outputStream << "{";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        outputStream << container[i];
        if (i + 1 < size) {
            outputStream << ", ";
        }
    }
    outputStream << "}";
    return outputStream;
}

template <typename T>
class MojVektor<T>::Iterator : public std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, T> {
private:
    T* ptr_;

public:

    Iterator() : ptr_{ nullptr } {};

    Iterator(T* ptr) : ptr_{ ptr } {};

    Iterator(T& e) : ptr_{ &e } {};

    Iterator(const Iterator& second) : ptr_{ second.ptr_ } {};

    Iterator(Iterator&& second) : ptr_(std::move(second.ptr_)) {
        second.ptr_ = nullptr;
        return;
    }

    Iterator& operator=(const Iterator& second) {
        ptr_ = second.ptr_;
        return *this;
    }

    Iterator& operator=(Iterator&& second) {
        ptr_ = std::move(second.ptr_);
        second.ptr_ = nullptr;
        return *this;
    }

    T& operator*() {
        return *ptr_;
    }

    Iterator& operator++() {
        ++ptr_;
        return *this;
    }

    Iterator operator++(int) {
        Iterator returnValue{ ptr_ };
        ++ptr_;
        return returnValue;
    }

    Iterator& operator--() {
        --ptr_;
        return *this;
    }

    Iterator operator--(int) {
        Iterator returnValue{ ptr_ };
        --ptr_;
        return returnValue;
    }

    Iterator& operator+=(size_t n) {
        ptr_ += n;
        return *this;
    }

    Iterator& operator-=(size_t n) {
        ptr_ -= n;
        return *this;
    }

    Iterator operator+(size_t n) const {
        return Iterator(ptr_ + n);
    }

    Iterator operator-(size_t n) const {
        return Iterator(ptr_ - n);
    }

    T* operator->() {
        return ptr_;
    }

    size_t operator-(const Iterator& second) const {
        return ptr_ - second.ptr_;
    }

    T& operator[](size_t index) const {
        return *(ptr_ + index);
    }

    bool operator==(const Iterator& second) const {
        return ptr_ == second.ptr_;
    }

    bool operator!=(const Iterator& second) const {
        return !(this->operator==(second));
    }

    bool operator<(const Iterator& second) const {
        return ptr_ < second.ptr_;
    }

    bool operator>(const Iterator& second) const {
        return ptr_ > second.ptr_;
    }

    bool operator<=(const Iterator& second) const {
        return ptr_ <= second.ptr_;
    }

    bool operator>=(const Iterator& second) const {
        return ptr_ >= second.ptr_;
    }
};

main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "MojVektor.hpp"

#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    MojVektor<int> a{1, 2, 3};
    MojVektor<int> b;
    std::copy(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin());
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << b << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

I tried manually setting std::iterator_tag, value_type, etc with using, using and inheritance, typedef, and typedef and inheritance. I also looked at some questions asked before, but they were related to list and inserters.
Also, in answers, they added inheritance, which is already present in my code.

5 hundred lines in the code is too much for a [mcve]. Hence, What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?

Ok i looked and this is what happens , so when i std::copy happens it actually copies the elements of vector but size_ stays the same, which means iterator works. Now how do i change the size_ with std::copy? @273K

std::copy() doesn't change the target size. This is your responsibility to resize the target to the required least size before std::copy() call.

Thanks for the answer and also for debugger, I totally forgot about debugger.

@Elnur1337 MojVektor& operator= -- leaks memory.  You failed to delete[] the old memory.  Better just to write MojVektor& operator=(const MojVecktor& rhs) { MojVecktor temp(rhs); std::swap(temp.arr_, arr_); std::swap(temp.size_, size_); std::swap(temp.capacity_, capacity_); return *this; }

@PaulMcKenzie Please don't recommend writing inefficient copies. Copies happen a lot, and they deserve to be written with care. See this.

@PaulMcKenzie no it doesn't, that is how it should work, google copy operator= and move operator=.

@Elnur1337 -- It leaks memory, period.  google copy operator= -- No, there is no need for me to google this.  First, there is no move being done, so why did you mention the move operator?  Second, this simple program shows the leak: int main() { MojVektor<int> a, b; b = a; }.  You are calling new twice for the arr_ member without any call to delete the previously allocated memory.  Unless you've come up with something that every C++ programmer hasn't realized, that is a memory leak.

Look at the rule of 3.  Where does your assignment operator do anything about the previously allocated memory?  I am not sure what other programming languages you have used, but C++ has no "garbage collector", where you can just continuosly call new[] on a variable, and magically the previously allocated new[] just "goes away".  C++ does not work this way.  Every call to new that you make must be followed up with a corresponding delete, one-to-one.

@PaulMcKenzie it is supposed to copy elements, that is what copy means and that is why it is called copy operator= and not move operator=. Look at rvalue and lvalue references. There is no move being done because it shouldn't be done there, because I WANT to copy from one array to another on heap. I'm creating new array with the same elements, pointer is not lost for any of two arrays. And i know there is no garbage collector in C++. Those are just two arrays separate from each other that have same elements.

If you insist on your wrong approach go ahead.  The code leaks memory.  I linked you to the rule of 3 -- you clearly see the example delete-ing the old data before copying over the passed in data.  The job of the assignment operator is to get rid of what the object had, and then copy over the internals of what is passed in.  If you do not do that (clean up the object's current state), you have a memory leak.  And just to let you know, your move assignment operator also leaks memory, all because you failed to clean up the object prior to the move.

@PaulMcKenzie i found out what you meant, thanks, but next time please be more specific, I thought your were talking about something else in operator=. Thanks.

I am glad you see what the issue is.  However I can't get any more specific than to say "memory leak".  A memory leak is caused by not deallocating the memory that was allocated.

The main issue is that, the std::copy expect a valid destination range to increment and assign values to it. In your code, the range b is empty, therefore std::copy can not iterate through it.
Therefore, according to your MojVektor implementation, you need to

either MojVektor::resize prior to std::copy: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/sMTeEfbKc
MojVektor<int> b;
b.resize(a.size(), {});  // resize!
std::copy(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin());


or use std::back_inserter : https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/3Mv5sf7aE
MojVektor<int> b;
std::copy(a.begin(), a.end(), std::back_inserter(b));




The other issues:

The std::iterator class is deprecated in C++17, and therefore it is not a good idea to make dependencies/ inherit from it.
You are missing the necessary type aliases (so-called "member types") to your MojVektor class.
You are missing the necessary type aliases to your Iterator class.

That means, you need to implement your container and iterate std-like, so that you can use the std-algorithms, properly.
template <typename T> class MojVektor 
{
public:
    // type aliases
    using value_type = T;
    using size_type = std::size_t;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using reference = value_type&;
    using const_reference = const value_type&;
    using pointer = T*;    
    // .... so on
};

// .....

template <typename T> class Iterator 
{
public:
    // type aliases
    using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;
    using value_type = T;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using pointer = T*;
    using reference = T&;    
    // .... so on
};


You have undefined behavior in your program.
When you declare MojVektor<int> b; you are declaring an empty vector.
When you call copy(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin()), you are writing to (and incrementing) b.begin(), which is the same as b.end() and neither dereferencable nor incrementible.
What you need in your test is back_inserter, which does a push_back to add elements to the destination container.

And here's what it'd look with when using a back_inserter and with misc. other corrections: https://godbolt.org/z/476rozEY9
